# Active Directory Group Membership not reflecting correctly in linux

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, samba, rhel6, winbind

Background:

On an isolated network.  Multiple RHEL6 Linux systems connected to a Windows 2012R2 DC.  Systems joined to domain and authenticating with DC.  Using IDMAP_RID.   No known changes to windows or linux configuration files.  Everything has worked for several years and only recently stopped.  There have been changes in the windows side in terms of security configuration but those changes are not well tracked.  I would have to ask those admins something specific to look at.  RH support has not been very useful.

ISSUE:

Some time in the past month most users no longer show the correct group information.
All users are automatically a member of "Domain Users" as this is the default windows group.  Nearly all users are in a AD security group named "Program Users" that I created.  When I execute "id" or "groups" for all accounts only shows membership in "Domain Users" and none of the other groups.  For the "id" command, sometimes it shows the group more than once.

id returns:

```
uid=###(username) gid=###(domain user) groups=###(domain user) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g returns the correct listing of all users and groups

getent group Program\ Users (and wbinfo --group-info) returns:

```
Program users:*:GID#:comma separated list of users
```

the list of users is correct and includes the users with missing data.

wbinfo -r does not return the correct list.

I've tried clearing /var/lib/samba/*.tdb but that does not help.

Some configuration data:

```
SMB.CONF:
[global]
   workgroup = DOMAIN0
   password server = server0.DOMAIN0.LOCAL
   realm = DOMAIN0.LOCAL
   security = ads
   idmap config * : backend = tdb
   idmap config * : range = 300000-399999
   idmap config DOMAIN0:backend = rid
   idmap config DOMAIN0:range = 100000-199999
   idmap config DOMAIN0:base_rid = 0
   template shell = /bin/bash
   winbind enum users = no
   winbind enum groups = no
   winbind separator = +
   winbind use default domain = yes
   winbind offline logon = false
   kerberos method = secrets and keytab
   client signing = mandatory
   server signing = mandatory

NSSWITCH.CONF:
passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files winbind
group:      files winbind
hosts:      files dns

SYSTEM-AUTH:
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
auth        [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
auth        required      pam_faillock.so authsucc deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=14 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 difok=4 remember=24 maxrepeat=3
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     required      pam_lastlog.so showfailed
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so

REQUEST-KEY.CONF
#OP     TYPE    DESCRIPTION     CALLOUT INFO    PROGRAM ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ...
#====== ======= =============== =============== ===============================
create  user    debug:*         negate          /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
create  user    debug:loop:*    *               |/bin/cat
create  user    debug:*         *               /usr/share/keyutils/request-key-debug.sh %k %d %c %S
negate  *       *               *               /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
create  cifs.spnego  *          *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
create  cifs.idmap      *       *               /usr/sbin/cifs.idmap %k
create  dns_resolver  *         *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k

KRB5.CONF
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = DOMAIN0.LOCAL
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 DOMAIN0.LOCAL = {
  kdc = server0.DOMAIN0.LOCAL
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a solution?
The solution seems to be

```
wbinfo -a user%passwd
```

Don't ask me why.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugr...cgi?bug=454670